# Unable to focus on a custom submit button in Angular @ng-select

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I am using [ng-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select) library. In multiselect, after checking the checkboxes, I need to have a custom submit button.

Everything is is working fine, but since key-board navigation is very important, I want to focus on submit button on TAB press.

Here is my code:

Template:

```
  <ng-container >
    <ng-select #entitySelector (remove)="onEntityChange($event)" [items]="people$ | async" [multiple]="true" bindLabel="name" [closeOnSelect]="false" bindValue="name" [(ngModel)]="tempSelectList"
      [virtualScroll]="true" placeholder="Search People"  (keydown.Tab)="onTabPress($event)" >
      <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
        <input id="item-{{index}}" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item$.selected" /> {{item.name}}
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ng-footer-tmp>
        <input type="submit" id="selectEntityBtn" value="Select" #selectEntityBtn class="btn btn-default select-button" (click)="saveData()"/>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-select>
  </ng-container>
```

TS:

```
  onTabPress() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      that.entitySelector.open();
      // that.selectEntityBtn.nativeElement.focus();
      document.getElementById("selectEntityBtn").focus();
    }, 1);
  }
```

**[Stackbiltz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzqqeb?embed=1&file=src/multi-checkbox-group-example.component.ts)**

Please help me out :)

Comment: You need (keypress)="onTabPress($event)"  ?

Comment: `onTabPress` is working. I need to focus submit button after that. Stuck in there

Comment: Try add to button `id="select-entity-btn"` Then in function `document.getElementById("#select-entity-btn").focus();` or with no # of an id.

Comment: Already tried that

Comment: Reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `event.preventDefault()` to disable default tab behavior on browser, so try this:

```
onTabPress(event) {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      that.entitySelector.open();
      // that.selectEntityBtn.nativeElement.focus();
      document.getElementById("selectEntityBtn").focus();
    }, 1);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

> **[Stackblitz working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzqqeb-e75exz)**

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

```
onTabPress($event) {
  var that = this;

  $event.preventDefault();

  setTimeout(() => {
    that.entitySelector.open();
    // that.selectEntityBtn.nativeElement.focus();
    document.getElementById("selectEntityBtn").focus();
  }, 1);
}
```

I think you will need to prevent the default-tab-behavior :)
You will need to pass the event.

regards